# Why is VLookup not running in Event Change sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble running a VLookup inside a Change Event sub. I have tested all other lines of code and made sure they work, so it's only the VLookup that's not working.

For brief background, I have two sheets. Sheet1 contains the ID (where it could have multiple IDs on separate line, hence the SPLIT function used below), Sheet 2 contains the ID and its Description. What I wanted to do is perform a VLookup upon value change and insert description for each ID as comment into the cell.

The line that is not working for me is: `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(IDs(i), Sheet2.Range("A3:B30"), 2, False)`.

I'm not getting any errors but it jumps right to exitHandler without running the reminder of the logic. I'm certain that the ID exists in the table for the VLookup. If someone can help me point out why it is not working, I will be very appreciated!

Below is a snippet of the code where VLookup is used:

```
With Target 
If .Comment Is Nothing Then 
     'do nothing
Else 
    .Comment.Delete 
End If 

If Target.Value = "" Then 
    .Comment.Delete 
Else 
    If InStr(Target.Value, vbCrLf) = 0 Then 
        IDs = Split(Target.Value) 
    Else 
        IDs = Split(Target.Value, vbCrLf) 
    End If 

    For i = LBound(IDs) To UBound(IDs) 
        If commentText = "" Then 
             'Add description for ID as comment
            commentText = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(IDs(i), Sheet2.Range("A3:B30"), 2, False) 

        Else 
             'Keep on adding description for each ID as comment
            commentText = commentText & vbCrLf & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(IDs(i), Sheet2.Range("A3:B30"), 2, False) 
        End If 
    Next

    .AddComment Text:=commentText 
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True 
End If 
End With

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `Application.VLookup` rather than `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` but doubt that that is the cause of your problem. For that you will have to examine the IDs() array of which we don't even know the data type. Start by inserting a loop into your code to Debug.Print the values you are searching for. That might give you a hint as to the problem. You should also add code to catch missing matches. All of that would induce me not to use VLookup at all. Construct an equivalent using VBA's `Find` method. It will be much easier to trouble shoot.

Comment: You say "but it jumps right to exitHandler" so I assume you have an `On Error GoTo exitHandler` somewhere in the code you didn't post.  Comment that out and see what errors you get.  When it crashes, have a look at the values and see whether anything looks wrong.  (As Variatus suggested, you will probably have to actually look at `IDs(i)` and verify that it actually **is** in `Sheet2`.  You might even like to write a dummy formula in Excel to ensure that what the VBA is trying to do will actually work there.)

Comment: Since you use the split function, IDs(i) is a string value. I bet your data contains numbers so make sure you convert the string to a number first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the part of the varible defintions is missing, i would guess that commentText is defined as `String`. If [`Vlookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel) performs a search without a match it will return an error, so the variable has to be defined as `Variant` otherwise you will get a type mismatch. You wont see the error when you use an `On Error Goto`-Statement. Also then you should check after a `Vlookup` if no error occured, i.e with the [`IsError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/gg278547.aspx)-Function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your replies. Indeed, it should be Application.VLookup and not Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup. I also had to convert IDs(I) to CLng to prevent 2042 error. Changing commentText to Variant is also needed to see the error code.

In the end, this is what worked for me:

```
 Application.VLookup(CLng(IDs(i)), Sheet2.Range("A3:B30"), 2, False)
```

Thanks again for all the help!